# How would you use pair-wise plots to test the effectiveness of k-means clustering?

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking over slides for a big data class. The slides suggest doing a pairwise plot of data (if not too many variables) to evaluate the quality of output from k-means clustering -- with each data point color-coded by its cluster. The slides say:

> If the (colored) clusters look separated in at least some of the plots. They won’t be very separated in all of the plots.

How would this tell you if a pairwise plot is effective? You would want the colors to be mixed up in the plots to make sure that you have genuine multi-dimensional clusters and not just groups of data points that are very similar on one variable?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is best illustrated with an example in R:

```
library(GGally)
data(iris)
```

**Actual labeling according to Species**

```
ggpairs(iris, columns=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), colour='Species', lower=list(continuous='points'), axisLabels='none', upper=list(continuous='blank'))
```

[image: Clustering according to Species.]

**Labelling according to kmeans clustering**

```
set.seed(1234)
iris$Cluster <- factor(kmeans(iris[,c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")], centers=length(levels(iris$Species)))$cluster)
ggpairs(iris, columns=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), colour='Cluster', lower=list(continuous='points'), axisLabels='none', upper=list(continuous='blank'))
```

[image: Clustering according to kmeans.]

From these pair-wise plots you can compare visually what elements kmeans assigns to the same group compared what elements belong to the same species.

Comment: thanks. But how does that relate to "If the (colored) clusters look separated in at least some of the plots. They won’t be very separated in all of the plots."

Comment: Well take a look at the red cluster.  It's very well separated if you consider `Petal.Width` against `Petal.Length` but less well separated if you consider `Sepal.Width` against `Sepal.Length`.  You can tell this by looking at the univariate density plots, the red curve overlaps much more the blue and green curves when you consider `Sepal.Width` then when you consider `Petal.Width`.